# registro.php y login.php funcionan en XAMPP pero no en el mi host doteasy

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

al hacer el registro y enviar los datos a la base me aparece el siguiente error:
Error: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'cabanas'@'localhost' to database ' taller'
La base la hice directamente en el hosting, la cheque y la base esta bien, registre el usuario ahi mismo y le di todas las garantias.
El codigo de registro.php es el siguiente:

```
<?php session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
header('Location: indexT.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$usuario = filter_var(strtolower($_POST['usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

$errores = '';

if (empty($usuario) or empty($password) or empty($password2)) {
    $errores .= '<li>Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente</li>';
} else {
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname= taller', 'cabanas', 'eCenter20');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = :usuario LIMIT 1');
    $statement->execute(array(':usuario' => $usuario));
    $resultado = $statement->fetch();

    if ($resultado != false) {
        $errores .= '<li>El nombre de usuario ya existe</li>';
    }

    $password = hash('sha512', $password);
    $password2 = hash('sha512', $password2);

    if ($password != $password2) {
        $errores .= '<li>Las contraseñas no son iguales</li>';
    }
    }

    if ($errores == '') {
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO usuarios (id, usuario, password) VALUES (null, 
    :usuario, :password)');
    $statement->execute(array(
        ':usuario' => $usuario,
        ':password' => $password
    ));

    header('Location: login.php');
    }
    }

    require 'registrate.view.php';

    ?>
```

No tengo la menor idea en donde puede estar el error, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Estas seguro que los datos: usuario, contraseña, nombre de la base de datos son los correctos?    por cierto  ten encuentra que con el mismo usuario y contraseña que te logueas en el hosting no siempre debe ser el mismo para conectarte a la base de datos.  y por cierto este archivo php  lo estas trabajando desde el hosting o esta  en tu maquina local?

Comment: hola Santiago, gracias por responder.Fijate  que en mi localhost funciona perfecto, cargue los archivos en el hosting y la base la volví a armar exactamente igual en el hosting para evitar cualquier problema incluyendo usuario, contraseña y le di todas las garantias (y puse otro usuario mismo resultado).Hoy me la pase todo el dia dandole vueltas y justo falla al hacer la conexion con el PDO, mañana vuelvo a escribir el código y la base.El error_log me indica que la falla esta en el inicio de sesion pero no es asi porque la forma de registro aparece y funciona, truena al cliquear el submit.

Comment: Bueno ten en cuenta que las sesiones trabajan a veces no de la misma manera en la que pruebas en el local que cuando lo subes a la nube, otra cosa que te aconsejaría es que intentes hacer tu conexión pero sin usar PDO  para ver como te va, con una conexión nativa al que le corresponda el motor de tu base de datos si es que logras conectarte o persiste el error;

Comment: Gracias Santiago por tus comentarios lo voy a intenter. Saludos